# Building a menu from a large number of pages?

Tags: menus, navigation

We have a large site (1,000+ pages) and we're looking to build a menu that contains our course offerings. The courses are controlled by WishList Member, so that only those a user is registered for show up. The WordPress menu builder is proving to be a stumbling block as its search isn't returning the proper pages.

Does anyone know how to build menus from pages? We have about 75 pages we'd like to add to the menu.

Comment: Sounds like custom code needed.  You are determining courses to show based on user registration.  How is that information stored?

Comment: WishList Member is handling all that. If I use the WP menu builder and add the page it behaves as it should (showing to those registered and not to those who aren't), but it's hard to find the pages to add them to the menu. If I search for the page title I don't always get the page I'm looking for as a result.